# Filtering Nested Data Regions in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, master-detail

I am trying to create a report where, as an example, it would look like:

[image]

I have been able to get this to work with subreports however there are two problems with this approach:

1. Subreports are extremely inefficient. They make a call to the database for every row and column for each of the subreports in Books, Stories and Articles.
2. When used within CRM 2011, you can only have one parent report per subreport which precludes being able to reuse subreports.  I have a Landscape and Portrait version of the same report (landscape has additional columns) and I would like to reuse the same subreports but this seems to be unsupported.

My question is whether I could craft a large dataset which contains all the joined properties and then nest a table within a parent table and use filters to only display the correct data within each cell.  To put it another way, the parent Table would have the Authors Name and Email, then there would be 3 sub tables, one in Books, stories and Articles.

I have tried putting in a filter into the sub-tables but I get an error saying:
The definition of the report '/ReportName' is invalid
The tablix 'tablix3' has a detail member with inner members.  Detail members can only contain static inner members...

This makes no sense to me because the 'email' Field is an inner member and it is not static.  Anyone out there know how I should better approach this?  Just to pre-empt the response "Change the design of the report", I can't.  This is how the users want to see the data.  I will accept answers which keep this layout but change the underlying implementation, but not answers along the lines of "make 3 separate reports".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is - can you nest one table inside another one and filter the nested table, the answer is yes. I have successfully done this.

If you are having a problem, there must be something else about your design that is causing the problem or there is something different about our environments. What version of SSRS are you using? Can you be more specific about your layout? For example, are you using a table or a matrix or a list to start? What steps are you using to insert the nested item? What kind of grouping do you have on the outermost item? The child item? Have you tried this with just one nested item to start?

Comment: I am using CRM 2011 running on SQL Server 2008 R2 (and whatever version of SSRS comes with that) and I am developing the reports in VS 2008.  I am using tables nested in tables.  I am using data from 2 different datasets.  I am passing in one parameter to prefilter the main dataset and then trying to use the current rows author id to filter the nested tables related "books".  Other than that there is nothing advanced about the report (no grouping, summation, custom code etc...).  Yes, I tried with only one nested item first and it did not work (so I stopped there).

Comment: Also, when I set up the nested table outside the parent, the Tablix property "Dataset Name" is the correct value "BooksDataset".  As soon as I drag and drop the table into the parent, this value changes to "AuthorsDataset" which is the parent tables dataset.  This is incorrect, I want the child table to still get it's data from its original dataset and only filter based on the parent rows AuthorId.

Comment: It does not appear that you can nest data regions that are from different datasets.  I have tried all combinations of List/Table and in all cases the nested table is forced to use the parent tables dataset.

Comment: That is correct - you cannot nest data regions from different datasets. If you are using SSRS 2008 R2 (assuming so from the SQL version), then you can use the Lookup function to get data from the second dataset as per my blog series: http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/03/19/sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-look-up-look-down-look-all-around-part-i/

Comment: Or you can create one large dataset as you initially proposed in your question. Either way, only one dataset for the entire group of data regions nested inside data regions.

Comment: It appears that your blog entry is exactly what I am looking for.  What I needed was the LookupSet Function. Victory!  Thank you so much!